# UK domicile with unremitting foreign income from a country with double taxation treaty

Tags: income-tax, united-kingdom, foreign-income

I am in a full time employment in UK but work most of the time remotely (from abroad). The fact that I spend time abroad is unrelated to my employment - my profession allows it and it's cheaper to live there.

According to Statutory Residence Test, I am UK resident because I meet none of the overseas tests and meet the automatic UK test about full-time employment.

I have a second income in the another country. This income is from a freelance work. The work is done as a non UK sole trader, outside UK, for a non UK company and the income is paid into a non UK bank account.

There is a [double taxation treaty between The UK and the other country](https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/515450/UK_Bulgaria_DTC.pdf):

I assume that, as a freelancer, my case falls under article 7, Business profits:

> The profits of an enterprise of a Contracting State shall be taxable only in that
>   State unless the enterprise carries on business in the other Contracting State
>   through a permanent establishment situated therein. If the enterprise carries on
>   business as aforesaid, the profits of the enterprise may be taxed in the other State
>   but only so much of them as is attributable to that permanent establishment.

Does this mean that as long as don't bring the foreign income into UK, I don't have to pay taxes on it?